# iPhone : OpenGL Rendering Transparent textures

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, textures

I have a texture that is partially transparent.  What do I need to enable so that it renders that part of the texture transparent?  Currently it renders the lower index texture in the transparent part of the texture so you get a texture on top of another?

Comment: What is the "lower index texture"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I remember this requires you to have a texture that has an alpha channel, something like `GL_RGBA` as internal format.

And you need to `glEnable(GL_BLEND);` to enable alpha blending and `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` to get the standard alpha blending where the image's alpha value decides how much it covers the image already there.